# React-Router: Nested Routes and Parent re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router v4 and am having a little trouble with nested routes. My parent route is a product detail page that uses an AJAX request within componentDidMount() to set the product data.

But when I click a link to render a route nested in the detail page the parent route re-renders and does the AJAX request a second time?

Here is some quick example code:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={AdminPage} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)

const AdminPage = ({match}) => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={match.path} component={Home} />
    <Route path={`${match.path}/products/:id`} component={ProductDetails} />
    <Route path={`${match.path}/products`} component={ProductList} />
  </Switch>
)

class ProductDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      price: ''
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    API.getProductDetails((response) => {
      this.setState({
        name: response.name,
        price: response.price
      });
    })
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
        <p>{this.state.price}</p>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/stats}>Stats</Link></li>
          <li><Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/bids}>Bids</Link></li>
          <li><Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/third}>Third</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/stats} component={Stats} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/bids} component={Bids} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/third} component={Third} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So how would I prevent the parent component (ProductDetails) from re-rendering when I open one of the routes nested in it? Thank you for any help!

Comment: It will re-render when a nested Route is clicked, that is expected behavior.  Is the problem that componentDidMount is being called when a nested Route is clicked?

Comment: Yes everytime I click one of the nested routes the componentDidMount() triggers re-sending the AJAX request - I would like to make it so that AJAX request only gets called the first time the parent component mounts.

Comment: I think it might skip the re-mounting if you removed the Switch in ProductDetails.  A Switch isn't necessary there since there.  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4578

Comment: IMO it would be better to have one route
`<Route path="/products/:id/:type" component={FooContainer} />` and handle your request in this one depending on the type. The nested is unnecessary.

Comment: Hey did you find the solution for that? I'm facing the exact same issue

Answer (score 4):

In my case, using `render` prop instead of `component` did not solve this.
My problem was about HOCs, I had to remove it from the route :

```
<Route
  path="/:locale"
  render={({ match: { url } }) => (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path={`${url}/login`}
        component={hocCausingIssue(LoginPage)}
      />
    </Switch>
  )}
/>
```

Became :

```
<Route
  path="/:locale"
  render={({ match: { url } }) => (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${url}/login`} component={LoginPage} />
    </Switch>
  )}
/>

// LoginPage
export default hocCausingIssue(LoginPage) // Now it no longer causes issue
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem where the entire parent component was being reconstructed when trying to call Redirect from a child component. [Here is the question I posted and answered myself haha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499179/react-parent-component-completely-reconstructed-when-using-redirect), I hope it helps you too!

tl;dr: Try changing the App's Routes to use render instead of component.

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" render={() => <LoginPage />}
      <Route path="/admin" render={() => <AdminPage />}
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is the expected behavior for React that the parent is re-rendered.

For the case of executing the AJAX request only once, one alternative that you should be looking for is to execute it when the parent component is **mounted**, which occurs only one time.

For instance, using functional components:

```js
function Route() {
    return (
        <Route path="/main" render={() => <Main/>} />
    );
}

function Main() {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Main mounted");
        // execute ajax here
    }, []) // this empty dependency array turns it into a "componentDidMount" effect
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Main</h1>
            <Route exact path="/main/tab1" render={() => <Tab1/>}/>
            <Route exact path="/main/tab2" render={() => <Tab2/>}/>
        </div>
    );
}

function Tab1() {
    return (
        <div>Tab1</div>
    );
}

function Tab2() {
    return (
        <div>Tab2</div>
    );
}
```